# How can i create an if statement within a for loop that breaks the for loop in c?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, if-statement, break

I'm working on some code in C. I'm trying to create a for loop with an if statement inside of it. And I want this if statement to break the for loop.

```
        for(int i = 0; i != n; i++){
            if(dashes[i] == '-'){
                break;
            }
            stillPlaying = 2;
        }
```

Basically, i want the program to check the array "dashes" if it finds a dash, it breaks the for loop and continues with the rest of the code. If it doesn't find a dash, the for loop is broken and stillPlaying is set to 2. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the code you have posted? The `break` statement therein *will* exit the `for` loop.

Comment: What do you think the `break` is doing? You have working code. Didn't you even try to run it?

Comment: What does this mean? "If it doesn't find a dash, the for loop is broken" Do you mean you reach the end of the array and the loop is not left via `break`?

Comment: I tried the following code but it didn't work as intended in my program, I'm assuming this means that it didn't work because of something else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your ways

```
    stillPlaying = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) {
        if (dashes[i] == '-') {
            stillPlaying = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    // stillPlaying is either -1 or 2 here
    // -1 if a '-' was found in dashes
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following

```
int i = 0;

while ( i < n && dashes[i] != '-' ) i++;

if ( i == n ) stillPlaying = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should work fine , as soon as - will come break will come into play , and loop will be exited .

Answer (score 0):

I tested it without problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char dashes[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '-', '4'};
int stillPlaying = 0;
int n = 5;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i != n; i++){
        if(dashes[i] == '-')
            break;
        stillPlaying = 2;
        printf("dashes:%c stillPlaying:%d\n", dashes[i], stillPlaying);
    } 
}
```